# Redundant if in code block

Tags: java, debugging, if-statement

I have following checks on input `json` and `schema`. I use intelliJ and it's static code analysis is saying *condition `shcema != null` is always true*.

```
if (json == null && schema == null){
    return;
}

if ((json == null && schema != null) || (json != null && schema == null)){
    throw new InvalidRequestException("error message");
} else try {
    JsonSchema jsonSchema = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault().getJsonSchema(schema);
    ProcessingReport processingReport = jsonSchema.validate(json);
    ...
} catch ( ... ) { ... }
```

Now, if i don't put in the first `if` condition where i am checking both objects, i might miss a use-case where its okay not to provide anything. Thats why i am using `return` in first if and not an exception.

What am i missing here

Comment: so whats the error or issue? can you provide more details please?

Answer (score 1):

Your first if statement checks if `json` and `schema` are both null and then in the second if statement you check whether one of them is null, right?

Well then the second if can be simplified to:

```
if (json == null || schema == null){
```

Why? Because at this point, if we know that `json` is null, then `schema` must not be null (or else it would have returned). Similarly, if we know that `schema` is null, then `json` must not be null (for the same reason).

By the way, if you want to check whether two boolean values are "different", use the XOR operator `^`:

```
if (json == null ^ schema == null) {
```

Comment: thanks for the tip around `^` operator. regarding if condition. the thing is that if **both** are null then function exits normally. if one of them are `null` then its an `exception`. how does **simplified version of if** satisfy both being `null` issue?

Comment: @EmAe If they are both null, the function would have returned! Your first if statement checks that, right? If the first if statement is true, then the second if statement won't even run!

Comment: okay. so what you are saying that i will keep first if statement (checking both null) and then i can simplify the second if with `^` operator or probably just check one of the object (as you wrote in your answer). Correct?

Comment: Yes that's right. That's what IntelliJ IDEA suggests. You can press alt+enter to see quick fixes for these warnings. @EmAe